# React Error @types/react"' has no exported member 'RefCallback'. Did you mean 'useCallback'?

Tags: react-select

### I'm use "react-select": "^5.3.2" and "@types/react": "^16.9.2"

I'm received error as below:

`[at-loader] ./node_modules/react-select/dist/declarations/src/components/Option.d.ts:2:21`

`TS2724: Module '"../../../../../@types/react"' has no exported member 'RefCallback'. Did you mean 'useCallback'?`

`[at-loader] ./node_modules/react-select/dist/declarations/src/components/Menu.d.ts:2:32`

`TS2724: Module '"../../../../../@types/react"' has no exported member 'RefCallback'. Did you mean 'useCallback'?`

`[at-loader] ./node_modules/react-select/dist/declarations/src/Select.d.ts:2:126`

`TS2724: Module '"../../../../@types/react"' has no exported member 'RefCallback'. Did you mean 'useCallback'?`

Please help me!
Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you please post the full component code or add a stackblitz url?